# What are the minimal components of a self-determined constitution?

Tags: constitution, democracy, law

I want to know what a constitution would look like if it were subject to the requirement of being freely chosen by those affected, including those of future generations. This is what I mean by "self-determined".

- What are the minimal components for such a constitution?
- What must it contain in order to prevent it being hijacked by a
  particular group, for instance, and then re-imposed by force?

I need the answer for [a study](http://zelea.com/w/User:Mike-ZeleaCom/in) I'm working on (no need to read about this).

Comment: this seems a bit too broad to be answerable. Since this is based on legitimate research, it may benefit if you narrow it down, either asking whether specific components are required or not, if some existing list of components is internally consistent or incomplete.

Comment: Also, what is your definition of the society/environment? Do you have feasible practical option of emigration (e.g. is it a constitution for a single city within a free-travel larger area? Or for an island/continent?). Witness the difference between political organization between a Kibbutz and USSR (in terms of ability to im/emigrate)

Comment: Another question is how much of an ESS do you wish your constitution to be? E.g. witness the famous [Tylerism](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/what-are-the-benefits-drawbacks-of-a-weighted-vote-based-upon-federal-taxes-paid) as far as the instability of typical democracy due to it not being a stable equilibrum because the strategy of voting for public treasury payoffs to voters will destabilize the equilibrum in the LONG term.

Comment: I try to clarify.  (1) About breadth: maybe the answers can be amended incrementally?  Then a single component would be enough to start an answer.  (2) The constitution should not be tailored to any particular place; instead it should be a model for any state that wants its constitution to be self determined.  Let the state's environment be the international world as it exists in the present day, and for the foreseeable future.  (3) Let there be enough stability to allow the constitution to remain self determined into the foreseeable future, or as far as possible.

Comment: Follow up question was asked on [philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7472/must-a-self-legislating-citizenry-guarantee-itself-freedom-of-speech/7474#7474) and I think it is still the same question even with the seemingly changed scope.